# Unnecessary property in definition of equivalence relation

Tags: logic, set-theory, relations

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Symmetric, Transitive and reflexive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65102/symmetric-transitive-and-reflexive)
>
> [Why isn't reflexivity redundant in the definition of equivalence relation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440/why-isnt-reflexivity-redundant-in-the-definition-of-equivalence-relation)
>
> [Dependence of Axioms of Equivalence Relation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39233/dependence-of-axioms-of-equivalence-relation)

Let $X$ a set and let $\sim$ a binary relation in $X$. $\sim$ is called a **equivalence relation** if:

1. $\forall x\in X$ we have $x\sim x$.
2. $\forall x,y\in X$ if $x\sim y$ then $y\sim x$.
3. $\forall x,y,z\in X$ if $x\sim y$ and if $y\sim z$ then $x\sim z$.

I think that 1 is unnecessary because by 2 we have that $x\sim y \Leftrightarrow y\sim x$. Then by 3. we have that $x\sim y$ and $y\sim x$ then $x\sim x$. Then 2,3 $\Rightarrow$ 1.

Am I right?

Comment: Must I delete question or not?

Comment: No; the question is simply closed, and a pointer to the duplicate is added. You should go read the answers there to see why you are not right.

Comment: Yes I was full understood, then I found another duplicate "Dependence of Axioms of Equivalence Relation?"

Comment: @ArturoMagidin In general titles are not explicit enough. Because this fact I didn't see a suggestive title. I always try to be very explicit in title as much as possible when i make a question.

Comment: I found the first one by doing a search for `reflexive transitive relation`.

Comment: The explicit title is the second and third. The first one is quite not suggestive.

Comment: The search also shows the first few lines of the body of the post. In the one I found, the first few words were "If a relation is symmetric and transitive, then it will be reflexive too. True/False?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right unless there is some $x$ that is unrelated to the other elements. If $x\sim y$ is false for all $y$, then 2 and 3 might both hold, but 1 does not.

In particular, the empty relation, which has $x\not\sim y$ for all $x$ and $y$, is symmetric and transitive, but not reflexive.

Comment: What do you mean with *empty* relation?

Comment: @Gastón: this is the relation in which nothing is related to anything else. (In other words, thinking of a relation on a set $X$ as a subset of $X \times X$, this is the empty subset of $X \times X$.)

Comment: An empty relation is one in which $x\sim y$ is false for all $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Not only when the relation is empty: it is enough that there's some $\,x\in X\,$ that isn't related to any other element. Then we ***must*** require reflexivity

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thanks then property 2 can't be used and can't deduce 1.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes you're right if there is some $x$ not related to anyone then can't be deduce that $x\sim x$.

Comment: Is surprising that the answer in this question was opposite to my other question about definition of topology http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151924/unnecessary-property-in-definition-of-topological-space

Answer (score 4):

no

what if there is no such $y$?

Comment: Do you mean for example the singleton?