# There is relation that is symmetric and transitive but not reflexive?

Tags: logic

Let $L=\left\{R\right\}$ be a language with only one relation symbol.
Consider these formulas:
$\Psi _1\:=\:\forall x\left(R\left(x,x\right)\right)$
$\Psi _2\:=\:\forall x\forall y\left(R\left(x,y\right)\rightarrow R\left(y,x\right)\right)\:$
$\Psi _3\:=\:\forall x\forall y\forall z\left(R\left(x,y\right)\wedge R\left(y,z\right)\rightarrow R\left(x,z\right)\right)\:$
I need to show $Mod\left\{\Psi _1,\Psi _2,\Psi _3\right\}\ne Mod\left\{\Psi \:_2,\Psi \:_3\right\}$.

So far, i understand the meaning of each formula, but i wonder which relation on any domain, can show that  $R$ is symmetric and transitive but not reflexive. Any ideas?

**EDITED**: Well, i looked at [If a relation is symmetric and transitive, will it be reflexive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65102/if-a-relation-is-symmetric-and-transitive-will-it-be-reflexive) and it really helpfull! but i want to find other examples just from curiosity ..

Comment: How about the empty relation?

Comment: @Slade, can you elaborate me about empty relation? what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

The empty relation on a nonempty domain is vacuously symmetric and transitive, but not reflexive.

Answer (score -1):

Quite generally, if the relation $R(x,y)$ holds, then from symmetry you have $R(y,x)$ and then from transitivity you have $R(x,x)$. So on the face of it symmetry+transitivity indeed imply reflexivity. However, note that we *implicitly assumed* that there exists such $y$.

So to conclude your question:

> **Theorem**: For a relation that's symmetric and transitive, and that for every $x$
>   there's a $y$ such that $R(x,y)$, then indeed $R$ is also
>   reflexive.

Comment: The implicit assumption isn't that $x\neq y$, it is that $y$ exists at all.

Comment: That's a matter of taste. If you assume that $y$ exists and that $y=x$ then it's like assuming reflexivity in the first place, which is kind of cheating.

Comment: It would be "cheating" if you didn't do both cases, $x= y$ and $x\neq y$. However, your argument, at no point, relies on any implicit assumption that $x\neq y$, it assumed there was a $y$ so that $R(x,y)$.

Comment: OK. I still think it's a matter of taste, but I'll edit my answer.