# Is there relation that is symmetrical, transitive and non-reflexive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

We must show that there exists some kind of $\alpha$ relation

 $\alpha ⊆ X \times X$  which has these conditions :

if this relation is I and II type.

I) symmetrical:
if $∀x,x' ∈ X : (x, x') ∈ \alpha ⇒  (x', x) ∈ \alpha$

II) transitive:
if $∀x, x', x'' ∈ \alpha : (x, x') ∈ \alpha (x',x'') ∈ \alpha ⇒ (x, x'') ∈ \alpha$

then there must be result of non-reflexivity for this $\alpha$ relation 
III) nonreflexive:
if $∀x ∈ X : (x, x) $ $\notin \alpha$

Is there any kind of relation like this?

Comment: Take $\alpha=\emptyset$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440/why-isnt-reflexivity-redundant-in-the-definition-of-equivalence-relation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X=\{x\}$ or $X=\emptyset$, then it's easy to show that $\alpha=\emptyset$.

Suppose $X$ has more than one element. Take $x\ne y$ - elements of $X$. Suppose also that $(x,y)\in\alpha$, then $(y,x)\in\alpha$, hence $(x,x)\in\alpha$, which leads to contradiction.

Thus, $\alpha=\emptyset$.

Comment: So, the answer to your question is, yes. $\alpha (x,y)$ must be false for all $x,y\in X$.

Comment: @DanChristensen It was not my question, but if you want to formulate the result in terms of predicate logic, then you're correct.