# Is every relation which is transitive and symmetric also reflexive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, relations

I have seen a proof that every relation which is symmetric and transitive is also reflexive.

if $A=\{1,2,3\}$ Then if $R=\{(1,2)(2,1)(1,1)\color{blue}{(2,2)}\}$

here $R$ is symmetric and transitive on $A$ but not reflexive right?

Can anyone clear up this confusion for me?

Comment: Is $(3,3)$ in it? Or $(2,2)$? This also shows it's not transitive.

Comment: yes its not there so it is not reflexive...that is my confusion

Comment: What's your confusion? It's not reflexive, you're right. It's also not transitive.

Comment: You may find [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440/why-isnt-reflexivity-redundant-in-the-definition-of-equivalence-relation) of interest

Comment: i am sorry that is not clear explanation to my question

Comment: What IS your question?

Comment: The addition (by @Joffan?) of $(2,2)$ to $R$ makes it transitive, and now $R$ *is* reflexive on its domain $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: @BrianO yes, I added $(2,2)$ on the grounds that the question was meant to illustrate a symmetric + transitive relation

Comment: @Joffan Then thanks, on OP's behalf too. I overlooked that, good catch. Adding the new pair in blue is an even nicer touch :)

Comment: Se also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440/why-isnt-reflexivity-redundant-in-the-definition-of-equivalence-relation) and also some questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/440).

Comment: Look at the proof and work out how it relates to your example.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Every relation that is transitive and symmetric is reflexive **on its domain**, where the domain $dom(R)$ of a relation $R$ is
$$ dom(R) := \{x \mid \exists y\, xRy \}
$$
(and where, as usual, $xRy$ means $(x,y) \in R$).
This is easy to show: if $x\in dom(R)$, then $xRy$ for some $y$, so $yRx$ by symmetry, and then $xRx$ by transitivity.

The domain of the relation $R$ that you exhibit is just $\{1,2\}$, not all of $A = \{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: ok it is pretty clear now

Comment: so finally does it mean that if a Relation R from Set $A$ to $A$ is symmetric and transitive then it is reflexive if $Dom(R)=A$

Comment: @Umeshshankar Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 6):

Foremost, this relation you defined is not transitive because of the following:
$2 \sim 1, 1 \sim 2$, but $2$ is not equivalent to $2$, which should be the case under transitivity.

Secondly, every relation that is symmetric and transitive is not necessarily reflexive. Generally the (false) proof proceeds as follows:

$a\sim b$, so then by symmetry $b\sim a$, then by transitivity, $a \sim a$.

However, this argument is based on the fact that $\exists \, b $ such that $a\sim b$, which does not have to be the case.

Consider the relation: $A = \{1, 2, 3\}, R = \{(1,2), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2)\}$.
It is symmetric and transitive but not reflexive. Note that there is no such element $b$ where $3 \sim b$.

Comment: A small quibble: the argument doesn't require that $b \ne a$, just that some $b\sim a$ exists at all.

Comment: Whoops, thank you for pointing that out! I suppose I was thinking there would be no need to prove reflexivity from symmetry and transitivity if it is already known that $ a \sim a$, but it is a mistake on my part. Edited and corrected.

Answer (score 2):

if you tack  $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $R=\{(1,2),(1,1),(2,1),(2,2)\}$ then $R$ is both symetric and transitive relation on $A$ but not reflexive because $(3,3)\not\in R$