# Does every element of a set need to exist in the relation for it to be reflexive?

Tags: relations

I came across this following problem:

> *Let $R$ be a reflexive relation on a finite set $A$ having $n$ elements and let there be $m$ ordered pairs in $R$, then:
>
> A) $m\ge n$
>
> B) $m \le n$
>
> C) $m=n$
>
> D) None of these*

---

I initially started with taking a simple example:
Let set $A$ was ${1,2,3,4,5,6}$ then one of the relations on it could be:
$R={(1,1),(2,2),(1,2)}$ which is reflexive **right?**

so this(according to my knowledge) showed that m doesn't have to be $\le$ or $\ge$ than n.   But the answer showed that I was wrong and $m\ge n$ But why does this happen?

---

Is it necessary for all the elements of $A$ to be included in $\mathbb R$ for it to be reflexive? That is, considering the previous example, do the pairs $(1,1), (2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6)$ **need to** exist in $R$ for it to be reflexive?
I have this conceptual confusion about what a reflexive relation really is and would be glad if someone could clear this out.

---

Another sort of counter question to this, then technically is an equivalence relation even possible for sets like *the set of natural numbers* as the following example illustrates what I mean:
lets take any relation $R$ defined on the set of natural numbers,

$R=${$(2,3),(3,4)$}

then what minimum number of ordered pairs should we add to make it an equivalence relation ?

---

Does the word 'minimum' allow us to not care about adding **all** the ordered pairs of natural numbers, that is, $(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)$ and so on...?

Comment: Look at the definition of reflexive... a relation $R$ over a set $X$ is called reflexive if and only if $(x,x)\in R$ **for every** $x\in X$.  The relation $\{(1,1),(2,2),(1,2)\}$ over the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is not reflexive because it does not, for example, contain the pair $(3,3)$ among others.

Comment: Worded another way, letting $\operatorname{Id}_X = \{(x,x)~:~x\in X\}$ be the identity relation (*equivalently identity function*) on $X$, a relation $R$ over $X$ is reflexive if and only $\operatorname{Id}_X\subseteq R$.  Recognize that $|\operatorname{Id}_X|=|X|$ and so given $\operatorname{Id}_X\subseteq R$ we have $|X|\leq |R|$

Comment: @Algebrology do not typeset relations with blackboard font... $\Bbb R$ is exclusively used to refer to the set of real numbers.  $R$ here in this problem is just used as a name for a relation...  Also, escape curly braces to have them not disappear when typeset.  `$\{1,2,3\}$` produces $\{1,2,3\}$ while `${1,2,3}$` the braces disappear as ${1,2,3}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I have made another edit to my post which extends my question here... Kindly take a look at it

Comment: One of the first [math.stackexchange.com questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/440) "Why isn't reflexivity redundant in the definition of equivalence relation?" is related.

Comment: "*Is an equivalence relation possible for sets (that are infinite)*"  Yes, of course.  "*What minimum number of pairs we need to add for this example*" Infinitely many because we were missing infinitely many reflexive pairs.  Beyond the infinitely many reflexive pairs we were missing, we would also require at a minimum $(2,4),(3,2),(4,2),(4,3)$

Comment: To give a "real-world example": consider the relation $R$ on people, where $aRb$ if $a$ and $b$ are contemporaries, i.e., if their lifespans overlap. Then certainly this is reflexive, since everyone lives at the same time as themselves. You must have $aRa$ for every person $a$ in your list; no one will be omitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is reflexive iff for **every** $a\in A$ we have $(a,a)\in R$. Note that this means that unlike transitivity and symmetry, reflexivity **crucially depends on the "carrier set" involved"**. So for example, $\{(1,1),(2,2),(1,2)\}$ *is* reflexive as a relation on $\{1,2\}$ but is *not* reflexive as a relation on $\{1,2,3\}$.

Note that one consequence is that a reflexive relation on a set must have *at least as many elements as that set*; in particular, addressing one of your later questions, every reflexive relation on $\mathbb{N}$ contains infinitely many ordered pairs.

This "context dependence" may feel odd at first, but it's a crucial aspect of the definition.